# Understanding Proof that generalized eigenvectors are linearly independent (axler)

Tags: linear-algebra

There is one part of the proof that I don't understand which I have marked in blue
[image]

I thought it was the case that $Tw=\lambda_{1}w$ for this very specific $w$ that we have constructed, so only the term that is being applied to $w$ is it true that $(T-\lambda_{1}I)^{n}w=(\lambda_{1}-\lambda)^{n}w$

So for the step marked in blue, it should be $=(T-\lambda_{2}I)^{n}...(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{m})^{n}w$ How are we allowed to turn all the $T$ into $\lambda_{1}$ if they are not operating on w? The reason I think this is the case is because for the step right before this one, we had to commute (according to the powerpoint by Axler himself) $(T-\lambda_{1}I)^{k}$ to where it is just in front of $v_{1}$ to get $w$

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on two terms and see if it is easier to understand

\begin{align}(T-\lambda_2I)^n (T-\lambda_3I)^n w &=(T-\lambda_2I)^n (\lambda_1-\lambda_3)^n w \\
&=(\lambda_1- \lambda_3)^n[(T-\lambda_2I)^n w]\\
&=(\lambda_1- \lambda_3)^n[(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^n w]\\
&=(\lambda_1- \lambda_2)^n(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)^n w\end{align}

If necessary, we can have an induction proof.